# Handle Route with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I do not understand much of react routes. But there is a site that clicks the links it changes the path of the url and the content of the page. But if you access the page directly through the browser, a 404 error occurs.

I would like to know how I get the same effect of changing content using javascript.

I tried

```
history.pushState({}, null, '/page');
```

This only changes the path in the url, does not load the contents as I would when I click on a link with the path.

**Edit: More information**
The route system is like this:
https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-react-router-5c978f70df91

[image: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/0*agefVFRDVNFwyMWd.gif]

I wanted to be able to change the content without having to click the links, I wanted a code that only did this with Javascript

This function  `history.pushState({}, null, '/page')` came very close but only changed the path of the URL that did not load the content.

Comment: Using react-router you can define routes to render certain components. That way when you change the url the correct component will render. Otherwise you will need to add logic that checks the url and renders the correct component. So in the root component of your app you would need to get the current url and decide what to render from there.

Comment: Can you post your full `react-router` code?

Comment: we need to see your react components to help solve problem

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `<BrowserRouter>` with `<HashRouter>`: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md

Comment: I have no control over the site, I can just inject javascript into it.

Comment: @BrunoAndrade you need to make that clear in your question!

Comment: I added more details.